# Coupled Ricci scalar action

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, variational-calculus

In the action where the Ricci curvature couples with the field $B^{\mu}$:

$$S=\int d^4x\sqrt{-g}\left(-\frac14F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}+V(B_{\sigma}B^{\sigma}) +R\lambda B_{\mu}B^{\mu}\right)$$

To obtain the equations for the field $B^{\mu}$ I did the variation w.r.t. $B^{\mu}$ and got the following:

$$ 2B^\mu \left( \lambda R + \frac{\partial V(B^2)}{\partial B^2} \right)=F^{\mu\nu}_{\space\space\space\space,\nu}$$

Is there any problem with this approach given that $R$ is now coupled to the field $B^\mu$? Is the equation I obtained correct?

Comment: *Is the equation I obtained correct?* Check-my-work questions are off-topic here.

Comment: Without having done the calculation, I see no reason why R shouldn't be coupled to $B^{\mu}$ seeing as it's non-minimally coupled in the Lagrangian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation seems correct. The "hardest" part is to realise that:

$$\delta (V(B_{\sigma}B^{\sigma})) = \cfrac{\partial{V}}{\partial{B^2}} \delta(B_{\sigma}B^{\sigma})$$

and the rest is a standard calculation. Regarding the Ricci scalar part, when you vary with respect to a field the variation of all other fields is zero. Since this term is a scalar quantity you can have it in your lagrangian.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, you can define any Lagrangian you want. Whether or not this is the right thing to do depends entirely on you and what you want.

With that in mind, the fact that $R$ is the Ricci scalar is immaterial to the question. The more interesting point to note is that no derivatives of your $B$ field appear and hence it represents a constraint on the system, like a Lagrange multiplier, rather than a new dynamical field.

But as I said, you can define whatever you want, and in particular you can define this.

**Edit:** Since it appears the OP intended $B$ to be the vector potential associated to the field strength $F$, my comments about $B$ representing a Lagrange multiplier are not applicable. Instead, my answer reduced only to "you can define whatever Lagrangian you like, whether this is a good idea or not is entirely dependent on the context of your specific problem."

Comment: I assumed the derivatives of $B$ were implicitly in the field strength tensors $F$?

Comment: I would guess, presumably, that $2F_{ab} = \nabla_{[a}B_{b]}$ here (since it shows up in B's EOM), but I completely agree with this comment.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer I didn't realize this is what they were doing when I wrote my answer. In any case, I've updated my answer appropriately.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that $B$ is the vector potential associated to the field strength tensor $F$  . So where I was trying to get at was for example knowing that the variation of $B$ vanishes at the boundaries , having $R$ multiplied by that factor it could be that $R$ diverges exactly at the boundaries (or is zero if the limits are at infinity) and that would be an indeterminate form. How would we handle it?

Comment: @MicrosoftBruh The answer to this question then depends entirely upon the boundary conditions you specify for the system. If your boundary conditions allow configurations for which the boundary terms in the variation are not negligible, then they are not negligible. It depends on the context of the problem you are trying to solve. For most common applications the boundary terms can be ignored, but this is not a universal fact. Instantons are famous non-zero boundary conditions and there is an extensive story relating such terms to GR actions, for example the Hawkin Gibbons term (See Wald).

Comment: @MicrosoftBruh There are many cases of modified gravity actions with fields non-minimally coupled to the Ricci scalar, and $R$ shows up in the field equations of motion